# Liberty profile not able to detect Spring Boot componentscan annotation and not loading application context

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I am deploying Spring Boot web application in Liberty 16.0.0.3.Have provided all dependency scope as provided and configured global shared library.But when I start the application Liberty not been able to load application context.

My configuration as below.

My pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp.testapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>testsharedlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>testsharedlib</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <runtime.scope>provided</runtime.scope>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>${runtime.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <scope>${runtime.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>



    <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <!-- <version>2.3</version> -->
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <skip>true</skip>
                     <!-- <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> -->
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/lib/*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>com.myapp.testapp.Appconfig</mainClass>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>true</DisableIBMJAXWSEngine>
                            <Class-Path>conf</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

         <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>


</project>
```

Liberty server.xml

```
<server description="Default Server">

    <featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>


   <library id="global">
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/jars" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <application context-root="HelloWorld" location="text-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="global" delegation="parentFirst"/>
    </application>

   <!-- Define the host name for use by the collective.
        If the host name needs to be changed, the server should be
        removed from the collective and re-joined. -->
   <variable name="defaultHostName" value="localhost"/>

   <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="adminpwd"/>

    <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
   <basicRegistry id="basic">
      <user name="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
      <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadminpwd"/>
   </basicRegistry>

   <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
   <administrator-role>
      <user>admin</user>
   </administrator-role>

   <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
   <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceSpecification="*=info:com.ibm.ws.classloading.*=ALL"/>


</server>
```

Comment: That war plugin configuration looks weird. How is a `mainClass` relevant for a non executable war?

Comment: Is there any kind of exception/stack associated with the failure?

Comment: @StephaneNicoll I have provide main class just Liberty to invoke application context loading.As it's not loading even if I don't provide anything with war plugin alone.

Comment: @covener I don't see any exception application is getting started properly but when I hit the URL my controller invocation is getting failed with 404 error.It's because of application context is not getting loaded when we use shared lib.Same application working without any issue when I bundle jar's in application WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: so essentially your question is: why does this work with dependencies in WEB-INF/lib but not in a shared lib?

Comment: @AndyGuibert yes thats right am I missing something in my war plug-in or  in server.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why this works with dependencies in `WEB-INF/lib` and not in a global shared lib is because the servlet that initializes your Spring application (`org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`) is coming from one of the jar dependencies.  Liberty will only scan the web context root (i.e. `WEB-INF/*`) for servlet classes.  It will not scan shared libraries for servlet classes.

As you found out in your other answer, the only way to link up a servlet coming from a jar in a shared lib is to explicitly declare it in web.xml (since Liberty will not auto-scan for it like it does for classes or jars in `WEB-INF/*`.

To confirm this, I wrote a simple servlet:

```
@WebServlet("/LibServlet")
public class LibServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
      throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }
}
```

Then I packaged this servlet into `servletLib.jar`.  When I provided this lib to my application using a shared library, I was not able to access the servlet at `http://localhost:9080/testapp/LibServlet`.  However, when I moved `servletLib.jar` into a `WEB-INF/lib` then the servlet was accessible.

Comment: I have another problem with my above configuration.If I use at Configuration and at Configurationproperties to load properties/yml file values Liberty not been able to load those values.Basically it not been able to load @Configuration class during startup.

Answer (score 1):

I am able to make it work by providing `WEB-INF/web.xml` in Liberty with global shared Library. Find below sample configuration.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.myapp.testapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>testsharedlib</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>testsharedlib</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <runtime.scope>provided</runtime.scope>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>${runtime.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-ws</artifactId>
            <scope>${runtime.scope}</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
<build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <skip>true</skip>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>

         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
</project>
```

**server.xml**

```
    <featureManager>
    <feature>webProfile-7.0</feature>
        <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>


   <library id="global">
        <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib/jars" includes="*.jar"/>
    </library>

    <application context-root="HelloWorld" location="text-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.war">
        <classloader commonLibraryRef="global" delegation="parentLast"/>
    </application>

   <!-- Define the host name for use by the collective.
        If the host name needs to be changed, the server should be
        removed from the collective and re-joined. -->
   <variable name="defaultHostName" value="localhost"/>

   <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="adminpwd"/>

    <!-- Define an Administrator and non-Administrator -->
   <basicRegistry id="basic">
      <user name="admin" password="adminpwd"/>
      <user name="nonadmin" password="nonadminpwd"/>
   </basicRegistry>

   <!-- Assign 'admin' to Administrator -->
   <administrator-role>
      <user>admin</user>
   </administrator-role>

   <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>
   <applicationManager autoExpand="true"/>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="9080" httpsPort="9443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint"/>

    <logging consoleLogLevel="INFO" traceSpecification="*=info:com.ibm.ws.classloading.*=ALL"/>

</server>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">

 <display-name>pctext</display-name>

 <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.myapp.testpkg.ApplicationConfig</param-value>
        </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>

 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

**ApplicationConfig.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.myapp.testpkg"})

public class ApplicationConfig {
  public static void main(String[] args) {      
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationConfig.class, args);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not clear from this answer what was changed to make things work.  Was it the `<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>` in web.xml?  It looks like pom.xml and server.xml are the exact same as they were in the original question.

Comment: @AndyGuibert to make it work I need to add web.xml and should provide DispatcherServlet configuration in web.xml.If I provide ServletInitilizer using annotation like @SpringBootApplication(scanbasepackages={com.testapp.textpakage}) Liberty was not loading application context when I use global shared Lib.But same is working if I package the app with all dependent jar in WEB-INF/lib.